# MSSOAP Uploading very large files to Sharepoint failing. Using Web Services

Tags: web-services, soap

I am using MSSOAP to upload files to Sharepoint 2010. But any file larger than 130MB failes to upload.
I debugged and found that: pSerializer->WriteString(_bstr_t(szTempFile)); fails when the file size is huge. It returns Exception [e_outofmemory].

Can someone help me out in finding the cause and the solution to this problem.

I have already modified the maximum upload size and execution time on sharepoint.

Thanks and Regards,
Aakanksha